# export HTML table to excel- save us issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have an Html table and I exported it to excel using jquery method `table2excel`.

```
function exporttoExcl() { 
    var date = $("#txtDate").val();
    $(function () {
        $(".testt").table2excel({               
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Excel Document Name",
            filename: "WeeklyAttendanceRpt_" + date,
            fileext: ".xls",
            exclude_img: true,
            exclude_links: true,
            exclude_inputs: true
        });
    });
}

<table class="testt">
<tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

Using the above code, I could the export and downnload it as '.xls' file. But I tried to do 'save as' operation of the downloaded file and it is saving as "htm/html" type. The default file format of the downloaded file is 'htm/html'. How can I set the default type to 'xls' or 'xlsx' instead of "htm/html" on the downloaded file.

Comment: "save as" saves the whole page which is a html file, as far i know there is no way to change the "save as" behaviour, maby create a custom menu with a custom "save as" option to save your exel with the desired extension